# Uprating for the MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

How good is it to uprate FET device to exceed the 150C junction limit absolute? What are the critical parameters to look for when uprating FET device?

Comment: It is safest to assume catastrophic destruction.

Answer (score 2):

MOSFETs designed for high temperature operation tend to use special (non-plastic hermetic) packages and silicon-on-insulator construction. Devices rated for operation at 225°C are available from [Honeywell](http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Missiles-Munitions-2/HTNFET_-_High_Temperature_N-Channel_Power_FET.pdf) and [others](http://www.cissoid.com/images/stories/pdf/Datasheets/CHT-NMOS80XX.pdf).

At high temperatures leakage increases exponentially, permissible drain current decreases, Rds(on) increases, and useful lifetime decreases drastically (exponentially, at best, and instant destruction somewhere north of 300'C most likely.

The manufacturer will guarantee nothing, so you are completely on your own as far as behavior and life. One batch from the same manufacturer might be different from the next, about all that is 'guaranteed' is that the characteristics will be worse than within the abs max ratings. There are legitimate applications where exceeding the abs max ratings is reasonable (for example certain 'products' need only have an active life measured in hours, minutes or even seconds) but it's not something to strive for.

I have been more involved lately in cryogenic applications (well outside of even storage limits for most devices). There are specialist [publications](http://www.extremetemperatureelectronics.com) devoted to extreme applications for niche markets.